# Gitlab-CI rules If/Changes do not work as expected

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

We are working with GitLab CI and a strange behaviour just happened. We are trying to only run a given job (e.g, `lint` here below) if `*.py` files are changed and we are in a merge request, not a simple git branch. If, for example, I am going to push a change on the `Readme.MD`, the pipeline's job `Lint` here will be executed where it should have not.

.gitlab-ci.yml configuration:

```yaml
image: python:3.7

stages:
  - pre-build
  - test

.ci_rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID'
      changes:
        - tests/*.py
        - tests/*/*.py
        - src/*.py
        - src/*/*.py
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"

lint:
  stage: pre-build
  script:
    - pip install flake8
    - flake8
  rules:
    - !reference [ .ci_rules, rules ]

# [... other jobs not relevant for the issue]
```

Comment: If you don't want to execute this job on the simple git branch why do you have `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` conditions in rules?

Comment: @czende I assumed it was to execute this process in all circumstances for the develop and main branches, however, for a merge request: only when *.py files shows changes, do you get where I would like to go ? I could update the post with a schema I have made too ? It could be easier to understand probably ? thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is in your job rules. Below are your numbered rules for better orientation:

```
1. $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID && changes
2. $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"
3. $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"
```

Let's consider some examples, variables values and job evaluation result with your rules. Remember if you don't use `when` keyword in your rule definifon then the job evaluation needs only one rule from the rules set to trigger a job.

- Create MR develop -> main with file change

```
1. rule ✅
2. rule ✅
3. rule ❌
---
job evaluation = ✅
```

- Create MR develop -> main without file change

```
1. rule ❌
2. rule ✅
3. rule ❌
---
job evaluation = ✅
```

- Create MR test1 -> main without file change

```
1. rule ❌
2. rule ❌
3. rule ❌
---
job evaluation = ❌
```

- Push to the develop branch

```
1. rule ❌
2. rule ✅
3. rule ❌
---
job evaluation = ✅
```

- Push to the main branch

```
1. rule ❌
2. rule ❌
3. rule ✅
---
job evaluation = ✅
```

Do you see it already?   I think your problem is that you have rules 2. and 3. mixed with rule 1. Therefore if you create MR without file changes, but your source branch is  `develop`, the job rule is evaluated as true (second example). I will suggest to have rule 1. in separated job (or template). Or use rules with `when` keyword and control it manually for example.

Comment: Wonderful @czende !! It is very helpful thank you for this clear and detailed answer. I have tried to remove the rule 2 and 3 to give it a shot within a merge request based on `main`. 

(1) I did change the gitlab-ci.yml -> no pipeline run (good).
(2) I did change the README.md for instance -> no pipeline run (good).
(3) I did change a py file -> pipeline run (very good).
(4) I did change again the readme.md -> pipeline run (very bad).

How could I manage to not run the pipeline for the point (4) ? it should not run right?

Comment: Your point 4 will run and it's ok. It will evaluate as true, because your pipeline source is "merge_request_event" and py file has already changed in the previous commit (comparing to target branch of the MR). So no matter what you will change from that point you already have both conditions evaluated as true (MR and inside this MR are changes to that file). I will suggest you to refactor it to push event and py file change. Push event is associated only with the given commit, not the whole MR.